# Vi substitution command

Tags: editor, command, vi, substitution

Using vi, how do I substitute the current line number somewhere into the current line?  For example, if the cursor is on line 10, I would like to put the number 10 somewhere on that line.

Answer (score 6):

You want to physically insert the line number, not just display it in the margin?  If so -

```
:s/$/\=line(".")/
```

This will append it the the end of the line.  Replace $ with ^ to prepend to the line.

Answer (score 4):

First:  the following are assuming you are using vim, not vi or a workalike or the Heirloom project vi.

Here are a couple of options:

First, if you're going to use `:s`, then put the cursor on your chosen line and:

```
:s/texttoreplace/<C-R>=line(".")<CR>/
```

where `<C-R>=` means actually hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> then type an equal sign.  The prompt
will change and you can enter:

```
line(".")
```

and then hit return, as indicated by `<CR>`.  At this point you'll be back at your `:s`
command with the line number inserted.  You can do the same trick in insert mode
as well (`<C-R>=line(".")<CR>`).

Second, you can use `\=` to insert the line number in a regular expression in the
same way, but this doesn't work in insert mode or in other places.

Finally, these are useful if you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> in insert and command line mode to insert the current line number:

```
:imap <silent> <C-A> <C-R>=line(".")<CR>
:cmap <C-A> <C-R>=line(".")<CR>
```

don't add the silent attribute to the `cmap` line: it inhibits output of the line into the command you're typing until you backspace.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
:s/texttoreplace/<C-R>=line(".")<CR>/
```

but this replaced the text with the number of the line that I was on when I issued the command (1) on every line, instead of using a different number for every line.

The following worked for me.

```
g/^/exec "s/texttoreplace/(".line(".")."/"
```

The `g/^/exec` executes the given command on every line that matches the regex `/^/` (i.e. every line).  The expression `line(".")` is then evaluated in the scope of the line being worked on, and not the line in scope when the command is typed in.